# Angular + Selectize get value in form create

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I'm using a very simple Angular directive to incorporate selectize:

https://github.com/paolodm/angular-selectize/blob/master/angular-selectize.js

```
app.directive('selectize', function( $timeout ) {
    return {
        link: function( $scope, element, attrs ) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $(element).selectize($scope.$eval(attrs.selectize))
            })
        }
    };
});
```

My whole form looks like:

```
<form>
    <input id="title" type="text" ng-model="post.title" />

    <select placeholder="Tags"
        ng-options='tag.name for tag in tags'
        ng-model='post.tags'
        selectize="{ maxItems: 3 }"
        multiple></select>

    <button ng-click="create( post )">create</button>
</form>
```

Selectize is wired up properly.

However, in my create function, I get `post.title` but that's it.

```
$scope.tags = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tag1'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Tag2'
}];

$scope.create = function( post ) {

    console.log( 'post: ', post );

};

// logs {title: 'input value'}
```

If I remove the `selectize()` call so it's a plain html element, and leave `ng-model="post.tags"` it works and I get expected value for tags.

With our without the selectize directive, I can run `$('select').val()` in the console and it correctly returns `[ "1", "2" ]` for example, which are the ids of the tags, which is what I want. They just don't get sent to `create` with selectize.

What's up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Angular/selectize myself, but I think your directive will only work if your options are hardcoded, e.g:

```
<select ...>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    ...
    <option value="n">OptionN</option>
</select>
```

Otherwise, Selectize is probably instantiated before `ng-options` creates them. Thus, [here is the directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/h5iPORWNnbjp5hkN7uNU) I use.